# Symfony Session Lifetime

Tags: php, symfony, session, cookies

I'm working on my first real Symfony (6.1) project and are currently implementing the User authentication following the official guide: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#access-control-authorization

So far I managed to set it up basically. Users can login and logout. But I noticed that the PHP session lives on seemingly forever (unless you explicitly logout). When I inspect the session-cookie in Chrome, its expiration date is set to 0 - which means end of browser session. However, when I close the browser and reload the page, I am still able to authenticate successfully.

I solved this by setting the attribute cookie-lifetime in framework.yaml to a specific value.

```
session:
    handler_id: null
    cookie_secure: auto
    cookie_samesite: lax
    storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.native
    cookie-lifetime: 120
```

But is this the right way to do it? Doesn't the session live on in the backend? Wouldn't I have to set a lifetime on the backend side to be safe that noone tinkers around with the cookie?

Sorry if those questions are nonsense, I'm still learning. Thanks for your info in andvance!

Comment: Not sure if it is just a typo here, but it is `cookie_lifetime`, not `cookie-lifetime`. Also, just to be clear, you are closing _all_ browser windows, not just the current one, right?

Comment: Yeah, it's a type as you can see in the code snippet. I am closing the tab and the entire browser afterwards.

Comment: Edit to above comment: It's a typo, but it still works

Comment: `Closing the browser` can be vague among different operating systems and different browsers.
In my case (macOS, Symfony6.2) 
(1) When i close `Firefox` from the browser toolbar and reopen it, the user is still `logged in`. 
(2) When i close `Firefox` from OS Menu (Firefox -> Quit Firefox) and reopen it, the user is `logged out`. 

In both scenarios the user is `logged out` with `Chrome`.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a cookie-lifetime > 0 the garbage collection will use this to purge unused sessions server side.

> When a session opens, PHP will call the gc handler randomly according
> to the probability set by session.gc_probability / session.gc_divisor.
> For example if these were set to 5/100 respectively, it would mean a
> probability of 5%. Similarly, 3/4 would mean a 3 in 4 chance of being
> called, i.e. 75%.

The problem with session cookies is, server side we have no idea when the client ends the session. In this case, the value of `gc_maxlifetime` is used when the garbage collection kicks in.

Comment: I'm having problems following the process. Will gc_maxlifetime set the time limit of a session server side? So this is the way to go to securely limit session lifetime? Where can I set it regarding the sessions created by the Symfony Security bundle? Sorry, as I said, I'm a beginner.